# Apple remote push notifications appears to behave different in sandbox- and production-mode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

While writing my original question I found an answer at Ray Wenderlichs [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial) on push notifications. In the section `Handling Push Notifications` I added the code to AppDelegate.swift as outlined in the first case.

```
if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
    updateFromSyncData(userInfo: notification)
}
```

After this change I can show the text from the push message in production-mode while the app is inactive.

Before I added the code above the payload would be handled while the app was active **and** inactive in sandbox-mode but only when it was **active** in production-mode.

When I noticed this I changed the code and tested while my iphone was connected (in sandbox-mode). And when it worked I archived, uploaded and reinstalled the app from testflight. I wandered in this circle a couple of times.

Is this difference in behaviour between sandbox and production by design?

I'm using swift 3 on xcode 8 beta 5 and the iphone is on ios 10 beta 6.

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if (application.applicationState == .inactive) {
        completionHandler(.newData)
        updateFromSyncData(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
    if (application.applicationState == .active) {
        completionHandler(.newData)
        updateFromSyncData(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
    if (application.applicationState == .background) {
        completionHandler(.newData)
        updateFromSyncData(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}

func updateFromSyncData(userInfo: NSDictionary) -> Void {
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        let tabbarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        let sVC = tabbarController.viewControllers?[1] as! SecondViewController
        // Show payload in SecondViewController etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four things you could look at:

1. **Completion Handler:** `completionHandler(.newData)` should be called **after** processing data and not before. Try:

   ```
   updateFromSyncData(userInfo: userInfo)
   completionHandler(.newData)
   ```

   The app has 30 seconds to process data. Frequent notifications with long data processing could also cause iOS to throttle remote notifications. Though I don't think that is the problem here. From Apple's documentation:

> As soon as you finish processing the notification, you must call the
>   block in the handler parameter or your app will be terminated. Your
>   app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to process the
>   notification and call the specified completion handler block. In
>   practice, you should call the handler block as soon as you are done
>   processing the notification. The system tracks the elapsed time, power
>   usage, and data costs for your app’s background downloads. Apps that
>   use significant amounts of power when processing remote notifications
>   may not always be woken up early to process future notifications.

2. **Main Queue:** The `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` delegate method gets called on a background thread. Check that the functionality in "// Show payload in SecondViewController etc." is executed on the main queue with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() { ... }`.
3. **Capabilities:** Check in Capabilities if the Push Notifications is enabled and also Remote notifications in Background Modes.
4. **Force Quit:** Are you force-quitting the app for testing? The app will not get a background notification in that case. As Apple's documentation says:

> ...if you enabled the remote notifications background mode,
>   the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state)
>   and puts it in the background state when a remote notification
>   arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if
>   the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch
>   your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch
>   your app automatically again.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your advice #1 and changed the order and called the completionhandler after the function. That solved my issue.